# Pass value to URL - REST style

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

```
<h1>Edit page of {{ $user->username }}</h1>
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'user.store']) }}
... the rest of the view
```

This is in my `login` view. The related code in the `store` method in the controller looks like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'))) {
     $user = Auth::user();
     return Redirect::route('user.show', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

and the `show` method:

```
public function show($user)
{
   return View::make('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

And I get `.../user/%7Buser%7D` as URL (and I want it to be, eg. `.../user/exampleusername`) and also an exception: `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object`.

When I `dd($user)` in the `show` method (or in the view, doesn't matter), I get simply `string[6] {user}`, which means I do not pass the `$user` successfully to the `user.show` route.

The official docs give this example: `return Redirect::route('profile', array('user' => 1));` which seems relevant to my case, which I think should look like this in my code: `return Redirect::route('user.show', ['user' => $user]);`?

Funny, though, if in the `show` method I try to take the user object from the session (`Auth::user()`), and dump it, as here:

```
public function show($user)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    dd($user);
    ...
```

it will still be NULL, but if I dump it in the `index` method:

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
    dd(Auth::user());
    ...
```

, then it returns correct object, full of parameters and values... I have no idea what's going on and why in one method I have the session object, but in the other I don't.

Any suggestions on how to go around this problem?

**UPDATE:**  I narrowed it down to this implementation in the `store` method:

```
return Redirect::route('user.show')->with('user', $user);
```

and in the `show` method:

```
$user = Session::get('user');
return View::make('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
```

Because apparently the only place where you can pass an array that will explode into single variables is in `View::make`, whereas in `Redirect::to`, `Redirect::action` and `Redirect::route`, etc., you must use the `->with('key', $value)` function. Those values then will be available in the `Session` singleton.

Nevertheless, I still get `.../%7Buser%7D` in the URL. And I don't know how to get out of this...

Comment: Try to `urldecode($user)` firstly in `show()` method

Comment: @bad_boy - I saw that in the `show` method, the `$user` object that I pass in `Route::redirect('user.show', $user)`, is actually NULL, whereas before I pass it, it is OK. My guess is that the syntax of passing an object to the route is different. I am trying to find relevant information in the official docs, atm, but if you have a suggestion - it is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` of the user to the `user.show` route - not the `$user` itself.

```
return Redirect::route('user.show', [$user->id]);
```

Comment: @Milkncookiez - has this question been answered? If so - can you please accept it - or provide more info